# Why doesn't my code print `os.path`

Tags: python, import, module

For the code:

```
def a(x):
    if x=='s':
        __import__('os') #I think __import__ == import
        print os.path
```

Why doesn't `print a('os')` print os.path?

---

My next question is: Why does the following code use `__import__('some')` instead of something like, `a = __import__('os')` ?

```
def import_module(name, package=None):
    if name.startswith('.'):
        if not package:
            raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")
        level = 0
        for character in name:
            if character != '.':
                break
            level += 1
        name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
    __import__(name)            #Why does it do this
    return sys.modules[name]    #Instead of `return __import__(name)`
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use __ import __ at all?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using a "import os" at the top of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@statictype.org's answer is correct (`__import__` does not bind any name in local namespace), but why ever do you want to print `<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/posixpath.pyc'>` or something equally weird depending on your platform?!  That's what `print os.path` will do once you've fixed your bug -- **what** are you trying to *accomplish* by that?!

You sure you don't want something completely different such as `print os.environ['PATH']` or `print os.getcwd()`...?

**Edit**: to answer the OP's follow-on question:

```
__import__(name)#why it do this
return sys.modules[name]
```

`__import__` does install what's importing in `sys.modules`; this is better than

```
return __import__(name)
```

if `name` contains one or more `.`s (dots): in that case, `__import__` returns the *top-level* module, but `sys.modules` has the real thing.  For example:

```
return __import__('foo.bar')
```

is equivalent to

```
__import__('foo.bar')
return sys.modules['foo']
```

**not** as one might think to

```
__import__('foo.bar')
return sys.modules['foo.bar']
```

Comment: hi alex,I have updated the examples, please help me to have a look

Comment: so ,'__import__'  must be the different name ,because  '__import__' Can not distinguish 'a.txt' , 'a.py' or 'a.rar',yes?,thanks

Comment: `__import__` imports a Python module, so a `.py` (or a `.pyd` [[on Win; `.so` on Linux]], or a `.pyc` directly, if existing and updated), **never** a `.txt` or `.rar`.

Answer (score 11):

`__import__` returns a module. It doesn't actually add anything to the current namespace.

You probably want to just use `import os`:

```
def a(x):
    if x=='s':
        import os
        print os.path
a('s')
```

Alternatively, if you want to import the module as a string, you can explicitly assign it:

```
def a(x):
    if x=='s':
        os = __import__('os')
        print os.path
a('s')
```

Comment: hi @statictype.org,I have updated the examples, please help me to have a look